# Running WCF Service on Vista 64 bit

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a simple console application which runs as a WCF service host. bsicHttpBinding is used.
When I try to get the service reference in my client ( another console app) I get this error

"*There was an error downloading http:// localhost:9999/TS.
The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http:// localhost:9999/TS'.
Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://localhost:9999/TS.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again*."

Please provide any pointers.

**App.config:**

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service
                name="TimeServiceLibrary.TimeService"
                behaviorConfiguration="TSConfig">
                <endpoint address="localhost:9999/TS"
                    binding="basicHttpBinding"
                    contract="TimeServiceLibrary.ITime">
                </endpoint>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="TSConfig">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to suggest that it is attempting to use SOAP 1.2 over a wsHttpBinding instead, but I'm not certain why yet (must be a lack of coffee). It might help if you posted the relevant parts of your config file, or upload it somewhere if it's too large

When you browse to http://localhost:9999/TS/?WSDL, what do you get?

Do you have a mex endpoint (metadata exchange) configured? See [here](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2006/11/09/WCF-Part-4-_3A00_-Make-your-service-visible-through-metadata.aspx) for an example configuration.

Comment: I get the same HTTP status 400 error on my browser.Not able to view my service metadata.

Comment: This is how my app.config looks like:

<configuration>
 <system.serviceModel>
  <services>
   
   <service name="TimeServiceLibrary.TimeService" behaviorConfiguration="TSConfig">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:9999/TS" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="TimeServiceLibrary.ITime">
   </endpoint>
    
  </service>
   
  </services>
  <behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="TSConfig">
     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
    </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
 </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>

Comment: So, no mex endpoint yet? I've added the config to your question for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the Basic HTTP binding uses SOAP 1.1 under the hood, which in turn uses a content-type of `text/xml`. The newer WS-HTTP binding uses SOAP 1.2, which uses a `application/soap+xml` content-type. WCF is complaining because it seems that your service is set up to use a Basic HTTP binding with a `application/soap+xml` content-type, which isn't going to work.

Maybe you could try adding `http://` before `localhost` in the address, or just use `TS` for the address, and specify `http://localhost:9999` in a Base Address element, e.g. inside the `<service>` element:

```
<baseAddress>
   <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9999/" />
</baseAddress>
```